# Is there any way to use syringe pumpe in pumping flow

Tags: physical-chemistry, equipment

I want to use syringe pump to pump water at 0.82 ml/min for 30 min ? Is that possible ( I read some paper use that but don't know how ?)

Comment: It depends which syringe pump do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be no problem when you use a syringe pump model with adjustable flow rate and sufficient volume (at least 30 ml).

Comment: If it's 30 ml how I cam use it for 30 min ?? Could you explain for me please

Comment: When you pump with a flow rate of 0.82 ml/min for 30 minutes, then the volume of liquid consumed from the syringe is 0.82 * 30 = 24.6 ml. So you need a syringe of at least this volume if you want to pump continuously for 30 min, without the need to refill the syringe in the meantime (which you want to avoid if possible, I think). And 30 ml should be a common size for syringes.